# Elasticsearch - searching through document keys

Tags: elasticsearch

Is there any way to have a full_text search through document keys? I have dynamic template and some of the documents doesn't have all the keys. So I want to search for "X" and the results will be all the documents that "contains" X in its keys or values.

Your help is highly appreciated!

Comment: If you are using Elasticsearch 6.0+ use custom _all field using "copy_to" functionality https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/mapping-all-field.html#custom-all-fields

Comment: @BarkhaJain didn't get you. this will copy the fields values into one field, how can I search through the keys?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(tested on Elasticsearch v7.x)

You can combine a [multi_match query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-multi-match-query.html) to search in values with an [exists query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-exists-query.html) to search in keys. For example, if you're looking for keys or values that contain the substring `X`, you can try

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "multi_match": {
            "query": "X"
          }
        },
        {
          "exists": {
            "field": "*X*"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

The query performance will increase if you can get rid of the wildcards in the `exists` clause, notably, the one on the left.

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works! but if I have something like: `"field": "Y*X*"` , is that gonna improve the performance? or it will be the same?